# Query on existing SDP attribute related to this patent

Tags: prior-art, claims, us20120195235

In reference to the patent: [US20120195235](https://www.google.com/patents/US20120195235)

How is this different from existing SDP attribute "a=lang" as given in
[RFC 4566](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4566.txt)?